# nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid topic doesn't exist

Tags: navigation, mapping, hector-mapping, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have set up a simple subsriber like the one in [this tutorial](https://answers.ros.org/question/250143/subscribing-to-a-topic-with-python/) and am trying to use it to get data from the nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid [topic](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html).  As the doc specifies, this data is in the form of an `Int8 []` so the only difference between the tutorial and my code is I replaced "String" with "Int8MultiArray"

I am running what I think is a fairly standard hector_mapping setup, and then I try and launch my subscriber node.  The node launches fine and sits there forever, never receiving any messages.  When I try `rostopic list` the topic is not there, despite the fact that the [documentation for hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping#Published_Topics) says that it publishes to this nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid topic.

It seems like I'm missing something to tell hector_mapping to publish, except that using `rosrun map_server map_saver` works perfectly, so clearly the data is there.  What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289062/nav_msgs/occupancygrid-topic-doesn%27t-exist/) by [FateInHaze](https://answers.ros.org/users/34720/fateinhaze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid  is not a topic, is a message type. the topic in the tutorial you point out is "/robot0/odom"

when you launch the packages in ros do in another console "rostopic list " ..... find the topic you like then do "rostopic info + <topic_name>" that will show you what kind of message the subscriber needs. then follow the tutorial and you should get your sub callback going.

---

Originally posted by [Troski](https://answers.ros.org/users/34702/troski/) with karma: 16 on 2018-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0